# Django NameError: name 'street_address' is not defined

Tags: python, django

Sorry for the long post as I am new to Django - have looked up other answers for the same error but none of them have been helpful in solving this problem.

I am trying to import data from csv files to Django using a python script. Since there are multiple files, the script has options to import those files one by one.

The import script shows a menu like below to the user to import data from the said csv files

```
    1: Import FileA
    2: Import FileB
    3: Import FileC
    4: Import FileD

    All: Import all files

    Q: Quit/Log Out
```

Now let's say I imported `FileA` which has the following code run successfully

```
        try:
            addr = Address.objects.create(
                street_address=row[2],
                suburb=row[3],
                pin=row[4],
                state=state1,
                country=count,
                created_by='initial_migration',
                created_dttm=dt.datetime.now(),
                updated_by='initial_migration',
                updated_dttm=dt.datetime.now()
            )
```

**The main issue I face is that while importing records from `FileB`, I need to refer back to the addresses imported from `FileA` and if there are multiple entries for the same suburb then I need to choose the one which has nothing contained in the `street_address` field (there will always be one such entry).**

When I try importing `FileB` and refer to the same `street_address` field that has been imported from `FileA`, I get the following error

```
addrs = Address.objects.exclude(street_address!='').values(suburb = row[9].strip() if row[9] else 'Unknown',state =row[11].strip())
NameError: name 'street_address' is not defined
```

Code for importing `FileB` is

```
         try:
             # print('{}-{}-{}'.format(row[11], row[1], row[2]))
             gender1 = Codes.objects.get(short_description=row[1].strip().title(),field_name='Gender')
             title1 = Codes.objects.get(short_description=row[2].strip(), field_name='Title')
             centre1 = Centre.objects.get(centre_name =row[0].strip())
             addrs = Address.objects.exclude(street_address!='').values(suburb = row[9].strip() if row[9] else 'Unknown',state =row[11].strip())
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use `!=` when filtering on queryset.

u can use [Q](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects) for this.

```
from django.db.models import Q

addrs = Address.objects.exclude(~Q(street_address=''))...
```

Comment: Thanks. Think that worked for the initial issue for `name 'street_address' is not defined`. Would `.values()` be the correct way like I have done above?

Comment: you need to use `.filter()` instead of `.values()`
[read more about queryset api here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/).

Comment: Tried ried using `.filter()` last time without much success. Will try again and report back.Thanks heaps for your help.

Comment: This worked. Guess I was doing it incorrectly before. Many thanks.